# Freeradius Log file Information

Tags: ubuntu, freeradius

I have installed freeradius in Ubuntu 10 LTS and I run freeradius in debugging mode as "freeradius -X" where i see the live debugging logs. Now I want to know where these logs (accept / reject) are saved as I checked the /var/log/freeradius/radius.log file but this file is empty.

Accounting information is successfully saved in /var/log/freeradius/radacct/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by simply redirecting the log.

Just run FreeRADIUS with -l and the path where the logfile should be.

For example like this:

```
sudo freeradius -l /home/pi/Documents/FreeRADIUSLog.txt
```

Also you can tell FreeRADIUS what it should write in there.

In radiusd.conf under "log" you can activate the authentication logs like this:

```
auth = yes
auth_badpass = yes
auth_goodpass = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page, you should be able to find the location of your request logs in /etc/raddb/radiusd.conf in the line starting with "requests = ". http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/radiusd.conf.5.html

From the FreeRADIUS Wiki, it sounds like this option is disabled by default: http://wiki.freeradius.org/config/Logging